# Entity Framework migration timestamp

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Very basic question.

When MSFT creates a migration ID, it prefixes the name of the migration with a timestamp.

```
For Example. 
201802132140243_initial.
```

Can someone explain how to read that?

```
year = 2018
month = 02
day = 13
```

and then?

2140243?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it is the time of day in hhmmss format, maybe to the tenth of a second. If it doesn't fit with the time when you created the migration, maybe it is in UTC time and you live in a different hour band than UTC (not sure about this because I live close to UTC time, so I have never paid attention to see if there is a big difference). So summing up, it should mean 21 hours, 40 minutes, 24.3 seconds